# UILabel max height with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios-keyboard-extension

I have a multiline UILabel inside a custom keyboard extension. I want this label to grow to fill the content up to a certain height, at which point I want it to just cut off the rest of the text.

Because the keyboard has different heights depending on the device and orientation, I can't just set a simple `less than or equal height constraint`.

What I tried was to constrain the bottom of the label to the top of the buttons below, with a `greater than or equal constraint`. This works to a certain extent, but causes the keyboard to grow in size as opposed to the label being forced to cut off its text.

How would I force the label to a max height, without directly using a height constraint on the label?

Answer (score 1):

Put the label in a `UIView` and constrain the view's height to `less than or equal`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a single number that the height should be less than or equal to. 

On different devices and in different orientations, the keyboard height is different. There is no one-fits-all number I can use for the height of the label. 

The solution must have something to do with the fact that when the label can't grow downwards, it cuts off the text instead of growing upwards.

Comment: if you constraint the view height and if u use auto layout, you don't need to worry about diff screen sizes @Aleksander

Comment: design your story board in wAny and hAny mode,and constraint your view. Rest will be taken care by auto layout.

Comment: @T_77 I am using `size classes`, but I cannot constrain the height of the label, as the label will have different room to grow on/ in different devices/ orientations.

Comment: i am not suggesting to constraint the label....put the label in a uiview and constraint the uiview